# Xamarin iOS change the default icon color to white in Light Mode

Tags: ios, xamarin, icons

How do I display the dark mode icon while in Light mode on an iOS device? I have been searching this issue for months now and every post seems to come to dead end or the solutions just don't work. Using Xamarin 17.3 & VS 2022 and and developing an app for both Android & iOS. We have the Shell's background color (<Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="141B4D") which is a dark blue. The default, black icons (battery, time & etc.) don't show well with this background (its a company color and can't change it.) Android seems to handle this on its own and I didn't have to make any changes & the light icons show on the dark background in both Light & Dark modes. But on iOS in light mode the black icons display but cannot be seen. In dark mode the light icons show just fine.
Awhile back I tried a suggestion to to tell it, in the shared app, to use the dark mode icons in light mode.

```
    <Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark=Black, Light=#141B4D}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark=White, Light=White}" />
```

But this doesn't work. So I really need some help in solving this. And if this is not the proper way to handle this a good alternative is welcomed.
Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3105-customizing-uistatusbar-syle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, seems that you just want the text or icon in statusbar to be white if i understand correctly. So a simple way to achieve is to  add the following code in AppDelegate:

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        ...
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Also, you have to add one key in info.plist

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Note: in Property List Editor, it will show *View controller-based status bar appearance*

Then in dark blue background, you can also see white icon. The following picture is in light mode.

[image]

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Here is the plist entry assuming this is entered properly:      
 ' <key>View controller-based status bar appearance</key>
  <string>No</string>'   here is the AppDelegate:      '        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        } '

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, the key in info.plist is **UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance**. It is a boolean value

Comment: I have updated my answer @Gary H. it worked for me.  I am glad to help if you have any question.